# Cannot reference block blobs with blank space in filename

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I am using Azure SDK for .Net (version 9.3.1, Platform .NET-Standard 2.0) for working with Azure Blob storage, and having troubles with referencing block blobs having blank space in the blob name.
I have uploaded a block blob JSON Test.json into a private container via Azure Storage Explorer 1.6.1.

Blob properties as per Azure Storage Explorer:

```
Name: `JSON Test.json`
URI: `https://<myaccountname>/<mycontainername>/JSON%20Test.json`
```

Now, I am trying to check whether that Blob exists with `CloudBlock​Blob.​Exists​Async()` method passing to `GetBlockBlobReference` non-encoded filename JSON Test.json

And getting FALSE as result.

Now, I am creating a blob programatically in a different container, passing the same filename non-encoded, using the same `GetBlockBlobReference` and getting created a blob with encoded filename.

```
Name: `JSON%20Test.json` 
URI: `https://<myaccountname>/<mycontainername2>/JSON%20Test.json`
```

What I am doing wrong? Why my block blob with blank space in its name created via Azure Storage Explorer is not found while referencing it with non-encoded filename? When creating a block blob programatically a passing non-encoded filename, why the filename gets encoded via the wire?

Please help.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
public async Task<bool> CheckExistsAsync(string connectionString, string containerName, string fileName)
        {
            var blockBlob = GetBlockBlobReference(connectionString, containerName, fileName);
            return await blockBlob.ExistsAsync();
        }

private static CloudBlockBlob GetBlockBlobReference(string connectionString, string containerName, string fileName)
        {
            return CloudStorageAccount
                .Parse(connectionString)
                .CreateCloudBlobClient()
                .GetContainerReference(containerName)
                .GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        }
```

Comment: this will be helpful - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/351

Comment: If the answer works for you, could you please help mark it as answer? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to update `WindowsAzure.Storage` to the latest version v9.3.3.

I used your code for the testing, and no issues with blob name contains white space.

Sample code:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AzureBlobConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {         
            string conn = "xxxx";
            bool x = CheckExistsAsync(conn, "f11", "222 json test.json").GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            //to see if the file exists or not
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.WriteLine("completed.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async Task<bool> CheckExistsAsync(string connectionString, string containerName, string fileName)
        {
            var blockBlob = GetBlockBlobReference(connectionString, containerName, fileName);
            return await blockBlob.ExistsAsync();
        }

        private static CloudBlockBlob GetBlockBlobReference(string connectionString, string containerName, string fileName)
        {
            return CloudStorageAccount
                .Parse(connectionString)
                .CreateCloudBlobClient()
                .GetContainerReference(containerName)
                .GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        }

    }
}
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: @VSorokoumov, can you help mark my post as an answer? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To check if blob exists try this code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var found = await blobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServerAsync(new Uri(filename));
```

You probably need to access file via Uri not by string in your last line. I havent really used async methods you used, but the code above is the code that works for me.